# Inquiry on Integrating Document Editing with in DocuSign Project

Tags: docusignapi

I'm working on a project where I need to provide recipients with the ability to sequentially edit and sign documents within the UI view when using DocuSign. After researching DocuSign, I realized that it doesn't directly support granting edit rights to recipients. To overcome this limitation, I am considering integrating a text editor with DocuSign.

Here's the required flow:

1. Create an envelope using DocuSign, granting the recipient the rights to edit the document.
2. Integrate a text editor into the process, allowing the recipient to make necessary edits.
3. Once the edits are completed, provide the recipient with a signing URL to sign the document.

My questions are:

- How can I ensure that the edited document is saved within the same DocuSign envelope?
- Is there a specific API or workflow to update the document within the envelope after editing and before signing?
- Are there any best practices or considerations when integrating document editing and signing in a sequential manner within DocuSign?

I appreciate any insights, code snippets, or alternative approaches to efficiently achieve this goal.
Thank you!

Comment: Can I ask if the requirements is just for the users to fill some data, update some minor text in the document, or they need full blown editor with rich text and make any and all changes in the document?

Comment: No, we need full blown editor with rich text.

Answer (score 0):

The DocuSign e-signature service scenario is that the "preparer" of the document is the person who then sends the document for signature. So I suggest:

1. Outside of DocuSign notify the recipient/editor/signer that they have document draft ready for their review and edits.
2. The recipient then edits the document and indicates to your app that they're ready to sign
3. Your app uses the document to create an envelope. Your app will use jwt oauth impersonation to act on behalf of a (paid) DocuSign user.
4. As part of the sending process, your app can set the recipient as an embedded recipient. This means that your app can then immediately display a signing ceremony window to the recipient
5. The recipient then signs the document they just finished editing.

There's also the issue of placing the tabs in the document. Using anchor text may be best

### Regarding

How can I ensure that the edited document is saved within the same DocuSign envelope?

Either replace the envelope's document or create the envelope with the edited document

Is there a specific API or workflow to update the document within the envelope after editing and before signing?

Yes, [EnvelopeDocuments:update](https://developers.docusign.com/docs/esign-rest-api/reference/envelopes/envelopedocuments/update/)