# Integrating DocuSign eSignature API with Document Editing Workflow

Tags: docusignapi

Hello Stack Overflow community,

I am currently working on integrating the DocuSign eSignature API into my application, and I'm looking to implement a specific workflow. I've successfully set up the functionality to send documents for signatures and allow recipients to sign using DocuSign's signing URL. However, I'm facing some challenges in implementing a more advanced document editing workflow.

Here's the desired workflow:

**1) Sender sends the envelope:**

This part is working smoothly; I can successfully send envelopes using the DocuSign API.

**2) Recipient opens the document in a text editor:**

I would like the recipient to be able to open the document in a text editor for further edits.

**3) Recipient edits the document:**

The edited document should then be signed using the DocuSign signing URL.

**4) Recipient can send the document to other users:**

After signing, the recipient should have the ability to send the document to other users.

**5) Other users can also edit the document:**

Subsequent recipients should be able to edit the document before signing.

**6) Senders should have a record of all changes made:**

My workflow:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uo0yo.png)

The original sender should have a comprehensive record of all changes made to the document by recipients.

I've been researching the DocuSign API documentation, but I'm struggling to find the right approach to implement these specific features. Has anyone worked on a similar workflow with DocuSign or has any suggestions on how to achieve this using the DocuSign eSignature API?

I would appreciate any guidance, code snippets, or documentation references that can point me in the right direction. Thank you in advance!

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please check (accept) the best answer to your questions. ***Thank you!!!***

Answer (score 0):

Your question is very similar to this [StackOverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77860957/64904)

See my answer there. Also, your desired workflow is not directly supported by DocuSign eSignature. Instead, your own application can implement your use case except for the signing part. Once the document is stable, create the DocuSign envelope and send it for signing.

### Document modifications after signing

In your steps 4 and 5, you imply that Signer 1 can sign the document, then signer 2 can modify and sign the document.

But this is inconsistent with common legal aspects of a contractural agreement: once someone signs a document, any alteration to the document invalidates the prior signatures.

DocuSign does have some support for this scenario--see the `requireInitialOnSharedChange` property of [Shared Tabs](https://www.docusign.com/blog/developers/tabs-deep-dive-collaborative-tabs). With the Shared Tabs pattern, if Signer 2 modifies the tab value set by Signer 1, Signer 1 will then be asked to initial the change.

But this doesn't cover general editing of a document in the envelope.

### Added

In your comment you still have the signer editing the document. DocuSign does not support that beyond entering tag (field) values to the envelopes documents.

If you want the signer to edit the document, implement that outside of DocuSign.

Comment: Please go through the following image in which I have explained the workflow which I am thinking to implement.

Is this corrrect?
https://i.stack.imgur.com/uo0yo.png